# How can I parse ast.Assign objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm trying to extract information on the top level assignments of my python code with ast, but am not too familiar with how to effectively parse it.

For example

```
import some_module

a = 1
b = some_module.load_number("some_path")

def plus(a,b):
   return a + b

c = plus(a,b)
```

I would like to be able to extract from this, a list of assignment expressions with data like the following:

```
{
'targets' : 'a',
'type' : 'static_value',
'value' : 1
},

{
'targets' : 'b',
'type' : 'function',
'value' : 'some_module.load_number'
'inputs' : ['some_path']
},

{
'targets' : 'c',
'type' : 'function',
'value' : 'plus'
'inputs' : ['var.a', 'var.b']
},
```

I care only about assignments. My current approach would work something like this.

```
import ast
with open("test_code.py", "rb") as f:
   content = f.read()
code = ast.parse(content)
results = []

def parse_assignment(node):
   targets = [x.id for x in node.targets] #extract variables names being assigned to

   ### Extract assigned values for primitives; only str shown for brevity
   if isinstance(node.value, ast.Str):
      values = [node.value.s]
      type = 'str'
   
   ### Function call version
   elif isinstance(node.value, ast.Call):
      values = [node.value.func.value.id],
      type = ['function']

   return {'targets' : targets, 'values' : values, 'types' : types}

for node in ast.walk(code):
   if isinstance(node, ast.Assign):
      print(node)
      results = results + parse_assignment(node)
```

I have two problems with the approach shown here:

1. I do not think `ast.walk` is a good idea here as it seems to be recursive and may pick up assignments within a function definition or something. I want only top level assignments.
2. The way I'm parsing the function names seems to be incorrect. In this example I want to parse out `some_module.load_number` but I instead get `some_module`. How can I get the full function name from an ast.Call object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ast.walk`, just iterate over `code.body` and pick out the `Assign` objects.

As for the function name, the `Call` value has a `func` attribute whose value is an `Attribute` node, whose `value` is the module name and whose `attr` is the attribute that actually references the function.

```
>>> >>> call = code.body[2].value.func
>>> f'{call.value.id}.{call.attr}'
'some_module.load_number'
```

Note that in general, the `func` attribute of a `Call` node could be an arbitrary expression whose run-time value is a callable.